# Ignore first '0' on both sides of query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to determine which items in the table OtherItems and also exist in ItemMain and which doesn't.

The problem is that some UPC's have a 0 in the beginning and some don't.

So I tried this query but the results don't look good.

```
SELECT * from OtherItems
WHERE UPC like '0%' and upc not in(select '0' + UPC from itemmain)
Or UPC not in(select UPC from itemmain))
```

Can some one guide me in what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You should really try to fix your data instead, if you have this problem you need to take care of it everywhere you use it instead of fixing it now, once and for all.

Comment: ok I would fix it. but now I need this query asap.

Comment: do the UPCs match in both tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
select * 
from OtherItems 
where not exists ( select * 
                   from itemmain 
                   where UPC=OtherItems.UPC or '0'+UPC=OtherItems.UPC )
```

or perhaps:

```sql
select * 
from OtherItems 
where ( UPC like '0%' 
        and not exists (select * from itemmain where '0'+UPC=OtherItems.UPC) )
   or ( UPC not like '0%' 
        and not exists (select * from itemmain where UPC=OtherItems.UPC) )
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but I'm getting a lot of items that actually do exists in itemmain

Comment: We are making a lot of assumptions: perhaps it would be good to post your minimal `create table` statements?

Comment: also, post an example which exists in both and is being returned, that might help too.

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't copy it right. it works like a charm. thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

UPC's generally do not have alpha characters in them. Why not cast them to a numeric which removes the leading zero should it exist on one and not the other?

```
SELECT *
FROM OtherItems A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT 1
      FROM ItemMain B
      WHERE CAST(A.UPC as DECIMAL(18)) = CAST(B.UPC) AS DECIMAL(18))
```

Comment: +1 (esp for `not exists`), but I'd caution that even if we know that about UPCs, we know nothing about how the OPs data is constrained!

Comment: its a good idea, unfortunately we do have some upc with characters

Comment: Bollocks. There goes that plan.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic needs brackets around the OR:

```
SELECT * from OtherItems
WHERE UPC like '0%' and 
    (upc not in(select '0' + UPC from itemmain)
    Or UPC not in(select UPC from itemmain))
```

with the brackets, the AND takes precedence, so you effectively get `(A AND B) OR C`

Comment: shouldn't the first `(` go a bit earlier? Also perhaps I can't count but do they match?

Comment: @jack i just added abracket to what was there, but you are right - too many at the end. regarding the logic, who knows, but there *could* have been a bug like this